# XSLT unable to remove line break before and after attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, saxon

I am trying to transform an XML schema with XSLT 3.0 with Saxon 9.9 HE into a JSON. The transformation is working. However, when I output the value of an attribute it is coming with a line break before and after the name. The XSD fragment is below:

```
    <group name="imapAttachmentDownloaderGroup">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>
            Configuration block definitions for IMAP attachment downloader delegate. It contains all the configuration
            block definitions that are required to configure the delegate successfully.
        </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <sequence>
        <element name="IMAPConnectorConfig">
            <complexType>
                <attribute name="imapHost" use="required" type="string">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>
                            This configuration block deals with the IMAP server name or IP address to where the 
                            connection is to be made to download the attachments.
                            Example: "outlook.office365.com" or "40.100.137.66"
                        </documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="imapPort" use="required" type="int">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>
                            The port to use to connect to the server, defaults to 993.
                            Example: "993"
                        </documentation>
                    </annotation>
                </attribute>
....
```

The SXL is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stylesheet version="3.0" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.proviseconsulting.com/ProcessConfig"
            xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform 
                                https://www.w3.org/2007/schema-for-xslt20.xsd">

<mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
<output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" media-type="application/json" normalization-form="true"/>
<strip-space elements="*" />
<!-- <template match="text()|@*"/> -->
<param name="delegateGroupName" required="yes"/>

<template match="/child::xsi:schema/child::xsi:group[attribute::name=$delegateGroupName]">
    <variable name="xx" select="attribute::name"/>
    {'groupName':'<value-of select="normalize-space($xx)"/>'
                  <for-each select="child::xsi:sequence/child::xsi:element">
                    ,'<value-of select="attribute::name"/>':{
                        <for-each select="child::xsi:complexType/child::xsi:attribute">
                            <choose>
                                <when test="position()=last()">'name':'<value-of select="attribute::name"/>'</when>
                                <otherwise>'name':'<value-of select="attribute::name"/>',</otherwise>
                            </choose>
                        </for-each>
                        <for-each select="child::xsi:complexType/child::xsi:attributeGroup">
                            <value-of select="attribute::ref"/>
                        </for-each>
                                                            }
                  </for-each>
        }

    <!-- <apply-templates select="attribute::name"/> -->
</template>
```

The output is:

```
    {'groupName':'
imapAttachmentDownloaderGroup
'
,    '
IMAPConnectorConfig
':{
'name':'
imapHost
',
'name':'
imapPort
',
'name':'
sslEnabled
',
'name':'
startTLSEnabled
',
'name':'
imapUser
',
'name':'
imapPassword
',
'name':'
credentialId
```

I have tried all the mechanisms that I could find in the posts assigning it to variable, normalize-space, normalize-space with string() with data(). Nothing seems to be working. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

=== Including complete example ===

XSL (removed all the comments and other elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stylesheet version="3.0" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.proviseconsulting.com/ProcessConfig"
            xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform 
                                https://www.w3.org/2007/schema-for-xslt20.xsd">

<mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
<output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" media-type="application/json" normalization-form="true"/>
<strip-space elements="*" />

<param name="delegateGroupName" required="yes"/>

<template match="/child::xsi:schema/child::xsi:group[attribute::name=$delegateGroupName]">
    <text>{"groupName":"</text><value-of select="attribute::name/normalize-space()"/><text>"}</text>
</template>
```

=== Output ===

```
{"groupName":"
imapAttachmentDownloaderGroup
"}
```

The input XSD remains the same. The Java code is as below:

```
        String xsdFilePath="file:///D:/workspaces/mtplatform/PlatformManual_V1/PlatformManual/ProcessConfiguration/ProcessConfiguration.xsd";
    String xslFilePath="file:///D:/workspaces/mtplatform/PlatformManual_V1/PlatformManual/ProcessConfiguration/ProcessConfiguration.xsl";

    Processor processor=new Processor(false);
    XdmNode node=processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new File(new URI(xsdFilePath)));
    XsltCompiler xsltCompiler=processor.newXsltCompiler();
    //xsltCompiler.setParameter(new QName("delegateGroupName"), XdmValue.makeValue("imapAttachmentDownloaderGroup"));

    StreamSource xsdSource=new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(new File(new URI(xsdFilePath))));
    StreamSource xslSource=new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(new File(new URI(xslFilePath))));

    XsltExecutable compiledXSL=xsltCompiler.compile(xslSource);
    Xslt30Transformer xslTransformer=compiledXSL.load30();

    HashMap<QName, XdmValue> parameterMap=new HashMap<>();
    parameterMap.put(new QName("delegateGroupName"), XdmValue.makeValue("imapAttachmentDownloaderGroup"));
    xslTransformer.setStylesheetParameters(parameterMap);
    XdmValue output=xslTransformer.applyTemplates(node);

    System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Comment: You can use `<xsl:text>':{</xsl:text>` to make sure you only explicitly output that text and not the line break your current code also includes. However, given that you use XSLT 3 and want JSON output it seems more adequate to use the `output method="json"` and have the code create the necessary XPath 3.1 map structure.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, as suggested tried <text>{'groupName':'</text><value-of select="attribute::name"/><text>'</text> it is still giving the same output wil line breaks ... any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem. When I try to apply my suggestion at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKm/1 I get the attribute names on one line `'IMAPConnectorConfig':{'name':'imapHost','name':'imapPort'`. Not sure however what kind of JSON that would be with two properties of the same name `name`.

Comment: As for my suggestion to use output method `json` and construct XPath 3.1 maps, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKm/. I had to adjust the structure to make sense as JSON as having several `"name" : "..."` doesn't seem to make sense if JSON is really the target format.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, yes you are correct, it does not form valid JSON, I intended to fix that later. However, I have added the full example. As observed, the line breaks exist, which make it as invalid JSON. The error from Jackson is 'Jackson Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10))'. The line breaks are actually there, upon string.replaceAll("\n",""), Jackson parses. Somehow I am not able to remove the \n's with XSLT.

Comment: Does that attribute `normalization-form="true"` on `xsl:output` really work for you? It would really help if you post minimal but complete samples to allow others to run the sample to easily reproduce the problem, don't see why we need to have to complete schemas or stylesheet code. Also try running from the command line first. If you want the `xsl:output` to have any effect I don't understand why you use the overload of `applyTemplates` returning a raw result, seems better to use a Destination where serialization happens.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, YES INDEED!!!, you pointed to the correct direction. I used a Serializer, Serializer ser=processor.newSerializer(System.out);
  ser.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
ser.serializeXdmValue(output); Now the output is coming as expected. {"name":"DelegateConfig"}. It seems the raw toString() has some predefined behaviour. The normalized-form="true" actually has no effect in my case. And also not setting the 'OMIT_XML_DECLARATION' has an XML declaration before the JSON output. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, also, as your above comment solved the problem, request to please add it as answer, I shall accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to control the text output, you can use the `xsl:text` element https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-text in the form

```
 <for-each select="child::xsi:sequence/child::xsi:element">
                <text>,'</text>
                <value-of select="attribute::name"/>
                <text>':{</text>
```

Furthermore, if you use `Xslt30Transformer` and want a serialized result in the form of text, like JSON, where the format is defined by the `xsl:output` in your XSLT, then you should use an overload of `applyTemplates` allowing you to use a `Serializer` as the Destination, i.e. http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#applyTemplates-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue-net.sf.saxon.s9api.Destination- with a `Serializer` created by the `Xslt30Transformer` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#newSerializer-java.io.OutputStream-), so in the simple case of testing the result with System.out you would use

```
Serializer serializer =  xslTransformer.newSerializer(System.out);
xslTransformer.applyTemplates(node, serializer);
```

In your Java case you have used the overload to create an `XdmValue`, take notice that its documentation http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#applyTemplates-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue- says it returns

> the raw result of applying templates to the supplied selection value,
>   without wrapping in a document node or serializing the result

As you have found according to your comments, if you have an `XdmValue` and want to serialize it in a controlled way, you are better off using the `serializeXdmValue` method of a `Serializer` set up as needed instead of simply calling `toString` on the `XdmValue`.